# "Cannot read property 'toFixed' of null"

Tags: python

I'm trying to create functions that will calculate the areas of different shapes. This is what I have so far, but on the lines that print the results I always get the external error "Cannot read property 'toFixed' of null" and I do not know what that means or how to fix it

```
import math

def displayWelcome():
  print "Welcome to my area and perimeter calculator"

def calcAreaCircle(radius):
  (3.14159) * (radius ** 2)

def calcPerimeterCircle(radius):
  2 * 3.14159 * radius

def calcAreaSquare(side):
  side ** 2

def calcPerimeterSquare(side):
  side * 4

def calcAreaRect(width, height):
  width * height

def calcPerimeterRect(width, height):
  (2 * width) + (2 * height)

def calcAreaTriangle(base, height):
  (0.5 * base * height)

displayWelcome()
radius = 3.56
area = calcAreaCircle(radius)
perimeter = calcPerimeterCircle(radius)
print('Circle   : area = {0:.2f}, perimeter = {1:.2f}' .format(area, perimeter))

side = 9.23
area = calcAreaSquare(side)
perimeter = calcPerimeterSquare(side)

width = 2.9
height = 14.22
area = calcAreaRect(width, height)
perimeter = calcPerimeterRect(width, height)

base = 7.97
height = 5.31
area = calcAreaTriangle(base, height)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "external error"? How exactly are you running the program, and what is the *exact* error message you get (copy and paste it, or take a screenshot if necessary)?

Comment: None of your methods computing a value is returning it, so each return one return  None

Comment: I have `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__` when i try your code, and this logic regarding my previous comment

Comment: The error I get (when I run it in trinket.io) says "ExternalError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of null on line 31 in main.py"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement

Answer (score 1):

According to @azro advice I make it work by adding return to your functions, and changing the `'your string'.format()` print.

And in your `displayWelcome()` function you used the python 2.7 way to print in console. Next time be aware that python 2.7 will be deprecated soon.

```py
import math

def displayWelcome():
  print("Welcome to my area and perimeter calculator")

def calcAreaCircle(radius):
  return (3.14159) * (radius ** 2)

def calcPerimeterCircle(radius):
  return 2 * 3.14159 * radius

def calcAreaSquare(side):
  return side ** 2

def calcPerimeterSquare(side):
  return side * 4

def calcAreaRect(width, height):
  return width * height

def calcPerimeterRect(width, height):
  return (2 * width) + (2 * height)

def calcAreaTriangle(base, height):
  return (0.5 * base * height)

displayWelcome()
radius = 3.56
area = calcAreaCircle(radius)
perimeter = calcPerimeterCircle(radius)
print('Circle   : area = {}, perimeter = {}' .format(area, perimeter))

side = 9.23
area = calcAreaSquare(side)
perimeter = calcPerimeterSquare(side)

width = 2.9
height = 14.22
area = calcAreaRect(width, height)
perimeter = calcPerimeterRect(width, height)

base = 7.97
height = 5.31
area = calcAreaTriangle(base, height)
```

Comment: okay awesome, it prints now! But it prints "area = null" and "perimeter = null" instead of the values

Comment: Not for me, I got the correct output : `Welcome to my area and perimeter calculator
Circle   : area = 39.815255024, perimeter = 22.3681208`

Comment: Did you try to just print like that : `print(area, perimeter)`, like that you will abstract the format method which looks like causing you problems ?

Comment: This is really weird...if I do it in the print(area, perimeter) format it prints (none, none)

Comment: Did you copy all changes I made ?